# Josephson junction exceeding the coherence length of the cooper pair

Tags: superconductivity, graphene, josephson-junction

In this recent paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03286, the authors present the data that they measured Fraunhofer-like diffraction pattern in a Josephson junction with graphene sandwiched between niobium (Fig. 3a in the paper). The dimension of graphene is on the order of microns, while the coherence length of cooper pair is typically on the order of 100 Angstroms. They even discovered pockets of superconductivity for a specific combination of magnetic field and gate voltage, which they attributed to Andreev bound states with multiple reflections (Fig. 3f-i). I am having trouble to see how phase coherence is retained over this kind of distance scale. Is the proximity effect able to dominate over the entire graphene sample?

Comment: The superconducting coherence length in niobium is actually 38nm = 380 Angstroms, and the insulating layer thickness actually goes down to 0.15 microns so the situation isn't as bad as you make it sound above.

Comment: @SamuelWeir But 0.15 microns is still larger than the coherence length. What baffles me the most is that after the electrons reflect off the graphene edge and travel across the bulk of the graphene, they still see supercurrent. This distance greatly exceeds the coherence length.

Comment: I'm not an expert on superconductivity and Josephson junctions, but I think that perhaps an important point here is that this is not an S-I-S junction (I=insulator) but more of an S-N-S junction (N=normal metal) because graphene is not an insulator but a semimetal. For a S-N-S junction the coherence length of the normal metal is apparently important because superconductivity can extend into the normal metal by a proximity effect. The coherence length for graphene appears to be a relatively long 5 microns ( http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0703052.pdf ). Perhaps that explains things.

Comment: @SamuelWeir that's part of the answer indeed: SNS systems exhibits stronger "coherence" than SIS (which in some sense can be seen as no coherent at all). To the OP, a question -> what could the reported effect be if it's not a Josephson effect ? There might be a lot of effects explaining coherence at long distance: percolation + fluctuations of the N region close to its superconducting transition is one of the example. Here it's certainly just because it's really low temperatures.